# Use xquery to read attributes and values

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I've got the following xml in a column that I want to be displayed in a certain way.  I've searched and searched but none of the solutions are specific enough to me so here goes.

XML:

```
<Top>
 <Branch>
   <BranchResult Version="1.0" Branch="Croydon" MilesToTravel="11" />
   <BranchResult Version="1.0" Branch="Hendon" MilesToTravel="11" />
   <BranchResult Version="1.0" Branch="Waltham" MilesToTravel="18" />
 </Branch>
 <Valuation>
   <ValuationResult Version="1.0" °IDENTIFIER="thisOne" GuideLow="3159" GuideHigh="4196" />
 </Valuation>
</Top>
```

I'd like the results to be like this

Branch1, Branch2, Branch3, IDENTIFIER

Croydon, Hendon,  Waltham, thisOne

This is how I see the SQL query but I'm probably missing a / or [] somewhere for it to work.  I hope you get the idea.

```
;WITH results AS (
SELECT branchNode.value('*:Branch/BranchResult/@Branch[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS Branch1
        ,branchNode.value('*:Branch/BranchResult/@Branch[2]', 'varchar(20)') AS Branch2
        ,branchNode.value('*:Branch/BranchResult/@Branch[3]', 'varchar(20)') AS Branch3
        ,ValuationNode.value('*:IDENTIFIER[1]', 'varchar(64)') AS IDENTIFIER,
FROM WWACGuidePriceLookup
CROSS APPLY res.nodes('//Top') AS branchNodes(branchNode)
CROSS APPLY res.nodes('//*:Top') AS ValuationNodes(ValuationNode)
where id = 2    
)   select * from results
```

Sorry this is my first attempt and I'm rubbish with the formatting.
I just need something to help me get going with fetching values and attributes.

Comment: "I've searched and searched but none of the solutions are specific enough" - Programming isn't like cooking where you search for a recipe for the dish you want to make, and if you can't find one you ask on StackOverflow. You have to learn how to combine the ingredients yourself.

Comment: @MichaelKay: You're right in that programming isn't like cooking. Your advice is tantamount to saying "just be better at programming". But that's not particularly constructive. What do you propose Stack Overflow is if not a place to ask questions when you've tried some things and have gotten stuck?

Comment: To learn to use any programming language you need to study the building blocks of the language and what they are capable of. You can't expect to master it by looking for examples of programs that solve exactly the same problem as the one you are trying to solve.

Comment: Below the existing answer you state, that there are namespaces involved. This you should have mentioned in your original post... In your own attempts I see, that you've tried to solve this with wildcards, but you'd have to set the `*:` in front of **each** element. Some hints: 1) Don't let SO-police discourage you from asking and 2) Start a new quesiton with more details. This was your first question and you got a harsh welcome. I've seen much worse!

Comment: Meta effect: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338492/540552

Comment: @MichaelKay: You didn't answer the question I asked and frankly your answer here and the meta conversation smacks of elitism. My opinion (for whatever it's worth) is that this community should be welcoming of beginners who have shown that they've at least tried *something* (which it appears to me that the OP did here). What you're suggesting is that people come here only when they've learned what are (in your opinion) the basic building blocks of their trade. But that seems to have a bootstrapping problem.

Comment: It's not elitism, it's concern for professional standards. It worries me that we have people practicing in our profession who would not be allowed to practice as plumbers or electricians or motor mechanics if they had a similar level of training. Perhaps using SO is part of their training; but in that case I think we have a responsibility not just to answer their questions, but to advise them on better learning strategies.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you're looking to do.

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#tmp') is not null
    drop table #tmp;
create table #tmp (x xml);
insert into #tmp (x) values
( '<Top>
 <Branch>
   <BranchResult Version="1.0" Branch="Croydon" MilesToTravel="11" />
   <BranchResult Version="1.0" Branch="Hendon" MilesToTravel="11" />
   <BranchResult Version="1.0" Branch="Waltham" MilesToTravel="18" />
 </Branch>
 <Valuation>
   <ValuationResult Version="1.0" IDENTIFIER="thisOne" GuideLow="3159" GuideHigh="4196" />
 </Valuation>
</Top>');

select 
    BranchNode.value('(BranchResult/@Branch)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as Branch1,
    BranchNode.value('(BranchResult/@Branch)[2]', 'varchar(20)') as Branch2,
    BranchNode.value('(BranchResult/@Branch)[3]', 'varchar(20)') as Branch3,
    ValuationNode.value('(ValuationResult/@IDENTIFIER)[1]', 'varchar(64)') as IDENTIFIER
from #tmp
cross apply #tmp.x.nodes('/Top/Branch') as b(BranchNode)
cross apply #tmp.x.nodes('/Top/Valuation') as v(ValuationNode);
```

I changed the xpath expressions within the call to the `value()` function. Specifically, I qualified the paths instead of using a wildcard and surrounded the path itself with parentheses before indexing into the path to produce a scalar value.

Comment: Thank you so much @ben-thul !
Your solution works perfectly with the xml.
If I change the top element to include xmlns it breaks, do you know why?
e.g.
   <Top  xmlns="http://www.mydomain.blah/">...

Comment: Namespaces are a whole different beast. I'd suggest looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx and try a couple of things. If that doesn't work, ask another question showing what you've tried and someone should be able to help you with that.

Comment: To whomever downvoted this answer, care to explain? I'm not in this for the fake internet points, but I *do* want to know if there's something I can improve.

Comment: @BenThul Probably because you didn't explain how/why this works or how is it different from the OP's code.